# Is it possible to hide all the element tag by using only 1 id name?

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm trying to hide certain tags by using one `ID` element, but seem like it only hide the first tag with the `ID` element that I used.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/mgm3j5cd/

How can i solve this issue? I wanted to hide the tag only with the ID element that I've declared. Appreciated for helps

Comment: [An `id` must be unique within a document.](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html)

Comment: its good if you dont have duplicate ID . you can use class indtead

Comment: I would suggest using a class. e.g. `<div class="className"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for the information. Um, may i know any others solution that i can use for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this tagged as `CSS`, so the following CSS in your page's stylesheet will work:

```
#hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Edit:

If you must only use JavaScript, you can do the following. Keep in mind that your document is already technically invalid by having multiple elements with the same ID, so this approach may not work in every browser. (I tested with Firefox 32).

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/88yw7LL9/2/

```
function hideByID(string) {
    var element = document.getElementById(string); // get first matching element
    var array = [];
    while(element) {
        array.push(element);
        element.id = string + '-processed'; // change ID so next call gets the next matching element
        element = document.getElementById(string);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].id = string; // revert ID to previous state
        array[i].style.display="none"; // hide
    }
}

hideByID('hide');
```

Comment: Hmm.. but, instead of using css, i wanted to apply the `display:none;` in javascript.. because i need to hide it based on certain condition.

Comment: Hi, @iglvzx .. could you explain for this two line of code

`element.id = string + '-processed';
element = document.getElementById(string);`

Comment: `document.getElementID(string)` will get the first element in the DOM with `string` as it's ID. So, to go to the 2nd/next element with that ID, we need to make it so the 1st/current element no longer has that ID.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution should be to assign 'class' attribute to certain elements you want to hide, like :

```
.XXXX
{
   display:none;
}
```

Perhaps, you want to specify some elements hidden with id, like :

```
#id1 , #id2
{
   display:none;
}
```

or

```
div#id1 , div#id2 //more accurate
{
   display:none;
}
```

but, unfortunately, you can't hide elements you want by using one ID.